# Apache - give access to "shared" directory on server

Tags: linux, apache

Running into a bit of an issue here whereas I would like to configure my apache server to let one subdomain access another's files (shared) to eliminate the need and overhead of direct URL calls.

For example, I would like my primary domain (site.domain.com) to access the images located in a "share" domain (share.domain.com/images).

The directory structure is as follows:

```
- subdomains
    - site
    - share
```

I have an site.domain.com/index.html file containing the following...

```
<img src="http://share.domain.com/images/img.jpg"> (works)
<img src="../share/images/img.jpg"> (does not work)
```

And no matter how many "../" I add I still cannot get out of the directory. Which is shown when I do a "view image" on the one that did not work.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I am not an expert.

I think the reason you cannot access the shared area is that is is not under your `DocumentRoot`, after looking at the documentation I think that what you want is the `Alias` directive; the documentation for which can be found at:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

An example of the usage is:

```
Alias /share path-to-share
<Directory path-to-share>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You would need to put that into the `<VirtualHost>` block in your configuration. Doing this maps `/share/imgages/img.jpg` to `<path-to-share>/images/img.jpg` so that you can access it like the files are in your `DocumentRoot`.

With this setup your example would become:

```
<img src="http://share.domain.com/images/img.jpg"> (works)
<img src="/share/images/img.jpg"> (should work)
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Lets imagine that your site is under `/var/www/site` (site.domain.com)
and your share folder is under `/var/www/share` (share.domain.com).

If you would like to have share as just a subdirectory accessible from `site.domain.com/share`
all you will need to do its to create a symlink from `/var/www/share` to `/var/www/site/share`:

```
ln -s /var/www/share /var/www/site/share
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, it is lacking details or supporting evidence. Please improve this answer as described in [answer], including using capital letters and punctuation.

Comment: Done Sam, sorry i hope this version is better

Comment: This looks much better. (I only fixed a couple minor things.)